# Linear Layout on a Canvas which contains an AdView

Tags: android, canvas, view, adview

Please help me to add a linear layout which contains a AdView on a canvas. How can I set the layout position parameters? I'm new to android. I'm unsure about drawing layout on Canvas. Help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: You mentioned that you've tried some code already. You'll be more likely to get help if you show us what you have so far and where exactly you're stuck / what specifically is going wrong

Comment: What is `Panel`? Wouldn't be simpler if you would use an XML instead? What ad API are you using? there should be some way to set the ad setup in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything else, to my understanding, the *`canvas`* is actually an AdView - my guess is you're using AdMob. But, that's a `View`.

A `LinearLayout` is a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and as its Javadoc description says, it's a view that contains `Views` - imagine it's a container of `Views`. You're supposed to use `ViewGroups` within `ViewGroups` only, not have them within `Views`. A `View` is supposed to draw something simple: a text, an image, a drawable or any combination of these. I would suggest to start reading the [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) article from developers.

Going back to your question: A `LinearLayout` will lay the textview after the canvas. If you need to add one on top of another use either a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`. Also, get used to use XML layout. [This link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/) should get you started.

Comment: Why don't you put both textview and canvas in the relativelayout?